# Why does the intensity of the escape peak from an Am-241 gamma ray seem to change based on the element placed in front of the Am source?

Tags: spectroscopy, x-rays, gamma-rays

I am trying to measure the value of Germanium's $K_{\alpha}$ x-ray by measuring the escape peaks produced by an Amersham $Am^{241}$ source x-ray striking a Germanium x-ray detector. The Amersham source contains an Am-241 alpha particle emitter that strikes some specimen of interest (either $Cu,Rb,Mo,Ag,Ba$ or $Tb$), causing the specimen to emit it's characteristic x-rays. In addition, the $Am^{241}$ source produces gamma rays that are sometimes picked up by the detector. All of these processes produce escape peaks that are displaced by a distance equal to the $Ge $ $K_{\alpha}$ x-ray energy.

For some reason, it appears as though the intensity of the escape peak produced by the $Am^{241}$ gamma ray depends on the specimen placed in front of the the x-ray aperture. The escape peak has a much higher intensity relative to the $Am^{241}$ gamma ray for the lighter specimens ($Cu$ and $Rb$), and a generally lower intensity relative the same peak for heavier specimens placed in the Amersham source ($Ba$ is the only exception, where the ratio between the peaks seems to increase). I'm not sure why this ratio seems to change with the element placed in the Amersham, since the $Am^{241}$ gamma ray shouldn't interact with the specimen at all. What could have caused this phenomenon? Here are some plots of my data, with the ratio between the gamma ray escape peak and the gamma ray peak listed above each peak

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am really interested into any plausible explanations